# NameError: name 'btn' is not defined while find element by XPATH using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

This Xpath and selector info copied from chrome elements inspector:

```
<button class="btn btn-white btn--no-margin btn--full-width _1XvaFLD3_IpAQNG-OJU2-H _1xNlj_ScH8hEMWzrkRt1A">Sign up</button>
```

CssSelector:

```
#main > div > div.Root__top-container.Root__top-container--has-notice-bar > div.Root__nav-bar.Root__nav-bar--has-notice-bar > nav > div.navBar-signupPrompt._3nonY0buM5Z1AF4aRrP8VY > p:nth-child(1) > button
```

That I have tried to find with:

```
button = wd.find_element(By.XPATH("//button[contains(text(),'"+btn-white+"')]"))
```

Which returns an error as:

```
NameError: name 'btn' is not defined
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049514/selenium-webdriver-finding-element-by-partial-class-name) that shows me how to find by a partial name.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`btn-white` is a class in the `button` element, not a text. And you can't use it as a variable it need to be `str` parameter

```
button = wd.find_element_by_class_name('btn-white')
```

Or

```
button = wd.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn-white')
```

If you want to locate by `Sign up` text

```
button = wd.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[.="Sign up"]')
```

Comment: Thanks! FYI the last solution 'locate by "Sign up" text returns an error: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: 'using' must be a string. Any ideas??

Comment: @GregIven try with single parentheses `wd.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[.="Sign up"]')`

Answer (score -1):

Does it work better for you?

```
button = wd.find_element(By.XPATH("//button[text()='Sign up']"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with :

```
wd.find_element(By.XPATH("//button[contains(text(),'Sign up')]"))
```