# Selenium Webdriver: Invalid Xpath with finding element using partial ID

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find elements using Selenium Webdriver in Python by partial class name. I am very new to programming and tried using advice from https://intellipaat.com/community/9218/is-it-possible-to-locate-element-by-partial-id-match-in-selenium and [Selenium WebDriver Finding Element by Partial Class Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049514/selenium-webdriver-finding-element-by-partial-class-name)

My code is as follows:

```
list5=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//[contains(@id,‘partial id’)]")
```

Please let me know what is wrong with this code, as it says it is not a valid XPath expression. Thank you!

Comment: Try xpath as `//*[contains(@id,'partial id')]`

Comment: What is the website and are there any iframes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `´` instead of `'`, try like this:

```
list5=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//[contains(@id,'partial id')]")
```

And since I don't know what exactly are you looking for, you might need to add tag name (`div`, `span`, etc.) after `//` i.e. `//div` or of course `//*` if you want any element.

For example if you do it for the page we are currently on you could write:

```
//div[contains(@id,'question')]
```

and you would get 3 `div` elements which have ids: `question-header`, `question` and `hot-network-questions`