# Using Partial Match in BeautifulSoup/Selenium Scraper

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying scrape data from this page https://www.flashscore.co.uk/cricket/.

Home teams have either of the following attributes:

```
<div class="event__participant event__participant--home">KSKS</div>

<div class="event__participant event__participant--home fontBold">Legends of Rupganj</div>
```

I had thought the following would allow me to use a partial match to scrape all home teams but it does not return any results. There are no errors.

```
homeTeam = container.find('div[class*="event__participant event__participant--home"]').text if container.find('div[class*="event__participant event__participant--home"]') else ''
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not able to locate `div[class*="event__participant event__participant--home"]` ? Is there any navigation once app is up ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56844649/10832190 : Check this post. It's a similar solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Selenium-Python I would do something like this :

```
for home_team in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='event__participant event__participant--home']"):
    print(home_team.text)
```

and that gave me the below O/P :

```
Sydney Sixers
Perth Scorchers
Brisbane Heat
Sydney Sixers
Brisbane Heat
Melbourne Stars
Melbourne Renegades
Brisbane Heat
Adelaide Strikers
Sydney Sixers
Sydney Thunder
```