# Locating and Find Element with dynamic ID using selenium in Pyhton

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

How to find and select an element that has a dynamic ID, that always changing every reloading the page,
this is the ID i want to select `id=x-auto-234-input` but the 3 digit number always changing, Any ideas?

Below is the script

```
<div role="presentation" class="MegaEntryTextField x-component" id="x-auto-234" style="width: 60px; height: 22px;">
  <input type="text" class=" x-form-field x-form-text " id="x-auto-234-input" tabindex="0" style="width: 52px; height: 18px;">
</div>
```

[image]

Can you suggest XPATH and CSS selector that work

Comment: Is there a full page we can see? With only this small piece of code, it's hard to tell what might overlap with other elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this limited piece of code, I think the most specific you can get would be this CSS selector:

```
div.MegaEntryTextField.x-component[id^="x-auto-"][role="presentation"]>input[id^="x-auto-"][id$="-input"][type="text"]
```

The main part here is`[id^="x-auto-"][id$="-input"]`, which only will select an element with an ID that starts with `x-auto-` and ends with `-input`, effectively only leaving out the dynamic number. The rest of the selector matches classes, tag names, and attributes, just for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[id^="x-auto-"]')
```

Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049514/selenium-webdriver-finding-element-by-partial-class-name/56844649#56844649) for more details