# Unable to extract specific text from XPaths in python for online URLs

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to extract specific text from specific xPaths from this url
https://www.discogs.com/it/artist/148415-Total-Eclipse-4

but nothing is displayed in the console. I expect the following output instead:

```
Artista 1: Total Eclipse (4)
Testo elemento 1: Jungle Fever
Testo elemento 2: Come Together
```

My script works perfectly for local .html files, but it doesn't seem to work when I try to use URLs. Here's the script I'm using:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

# Ask the user to enter the Discogs URL
url = input("Enter the Discogs URL: ")

# Make an HTTP request to get the HTML content of the page
response = requests.get(url)
html_content = response.text

# Parse HTML using lxml
tree = html.fromstring(html_content)

# Use a generic XPath to capture as many "h1" and "a" elements as desired
elements = tree.xpath('//*[starts-with(local-name(), "div")][4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/h1 | //*[starts-with(local-name(), "div")][4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/table//*[starts-with(local-name(), "tr")][2]/td[5]/a | //*[starts-with(local-name(), "div")][4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/table//*[starts-with(local-name(), "tr")]/td[5]/a')

# Counters to keep track of "a" item artists and lyrics
artist_counter = 1
text_counter = 1

# Print the text of the "h1" and "a" elements found in sequence
for element in elements:
    if element.tag == 'h1':
        print(f"Artista {artist_counter}: {element.text.strip()}")
        artist_counter += 1
    else:
        print(f"Testo elemento {text_counter}: {element.text.strip()}")
        text_counter += 1
```

Comment: That web page is probably populated using javascript after the page loads, which means you'll never see the data you want when using the `requests` module. You would either need to use an actual browser (e.g. via selenium or playwright), or you would need to examine the javascript calls and see if there's a URL you can retrieve that returns the actual data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a dynamic webpage and different pieces of information are getting loaded with Javascript. So, using simple `requests` will not work as it only returns the static web content.

Here's how you can accomplish your task using `Selenium`:

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://www.discogs.com/it/artist/148415-Total-Eclipse-4"
driver.get(url)

title = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h1[class^="title_"]'))).text
print(f"Artista 1: {title}")

container = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class^="textWithCovers_"]>div')))

for i, element in enumerate(container, start=1):
    artist = element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td[class^="title_"]> a').text
    print(f"Testo elemento {i}: {artist}")
```

output:

```
Artista 1: Total Eclipse (4)
Testo elemento 1: Jungle Fever
Testo elemento 2: Come Together
```

[image: class containing the desired tabs]

- if you notice, we've used [Selenium WebDriver Finding Element by Partial Class Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049514/selenium-webdriver-finding-element-by-partial-class-name/56844649#56844649) to locate the element since there're few dynamic letters at the end in the class names. for example `class="textWithCovers_2o9C3"`

Comment: Just one question, I tried to search for the `"textWithCovers_"` class but I didn't find that class, how did you find it on that URL? With DevTools I can't find it

Comment: Please check the answer, I've updated it with the explanation to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for your tips, but they didn't work for my other solution. I used Selenium like you, but I was still wrong. Could you help me with this, please?https://superuser.com/questions/1801841/nosuchelementexception-while-scraping-data-from-discogs-url-using-selenium

Comment: I've answered your 2nd question there https://superuser.com/questions/1801841/nosuchelementexception-while-scraping-data-from-discogs-url-using-selenium/1801975#1801975