# Xpath for combination of text with apostrophe and links

Tags: xpath

```
<div class="plan"> don't get <a class="ensure" href="https://google.com">linktext</a> more sentence here </div>
```

I'm trying to get Xpath to assert the whole sentence which is all the text with apostrophe and (link + its text) in 1 expression as below. But its not working, please help?

```
//div[contains(text() = 'don\'t get more sentence here']/a[contains(text()='linktext')]/@href']
```

Comment: Can you please show us the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish with all of this, but here is one expression that should work:

```
//div[text()[contains(., "don't get")] and 
      text()[contains(., "more sentence here")]
     ]/a[contains(text(), 'linktext')]/@href
```

This should also work:

```
//div[contains(., "don't get") and 
      contains(., "more sentence here")
     ]/a[contains(., 'linktext')]/@href
```

The `div` in your example has two separate text nodes, so you can't use a single `contains()` on both of them at the same time.

Comment: Thanks it worked, I implemented it differently based on ur input

Answer (score 1):

The way you specify an apostrophe without conflicting with single quote delimiters will [vary per the language hosting the XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482352/xquery-looking-for-text-with-single-quote).

You likely can skirt the issue here, however, if, as I suspect, you're over specifying the targeted `div`.  If matching on the link anchor text and the end of the `div` suffice, you can use this XPath:

```
//div[a[. = 'linktext'] and ends-with(., ' more sentence here ')]
```

Comment: I implemented it differently based on ur input. Thanks