# Execution of js code with xpath search fails in python/selenium

Tags: javascript, python, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Below JS code(run via python selenium) searches for text in the document,locates the tag and pulls out the css attributes of the HTML element.

```
styleJSON = driver.execute_script("""function getElementByXpath(path){return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);}function getPathTo(element) {if(element.id!=='') return 'id("'+element.id+'")';if (element===document.body) return '//'+element.tagName; var ix= 0;var siblings= element.parentNode.childNodes; for (var i= 0; i<siblings.length; i++) {var sibling= siblings[i];if (sibling===element)return getPathTo(element.parentNode)+'/'+element.tagName+'['+(ix+1)+']';if (sibling.nodeType===1 && sibling.tagName===element.tagName)ix++;}}var not_found=[],styleSheet=[],pos,temp;try{var corpus=JSON.parse(arguments[0]);console.log(corpus);for(var k = 0; k < corpus.length; k++){pos=0; elements = getElementByXpath('//*[normalize-space(text())=normalize-space('+cleanStringForXpath(corpus[k])+')]');elem=elements.iterateNext();if(!elem){not_found.push(corpus[k]);} while(elem) { pos++;temp = {'corpus': corpus[k], 'font_size':window.getComputedStyle(elem).fontSize, 'font_color':window.getComputedStyle(elem).color,'font_weight':window.getComputedStyle(elem).fontWeight,'font_family':window.getComputedStyle(elem).fontFamily,'tag': elem.tagName,'xpath':getPathTo(elem),'pos':pos,'text_decoration':window.getComputedStyle(elem).textDecoration}; if(temp.tag!=='SCRIPT' || temp.tag!=='TITLE'){styleSheet.push(temp);console.log(temp);}elem=elements.iterateNext();}}}catch(err){console.log(err);}console.log(not_found);return JSON.stringify({stylesheet:styleSheet,not_found: not_found});""", json.dumps(corpus, ensure_ascii=False, encoding='utf-8'))
```

My problem is when text with single and double quotes are passed in.I tried using the function **cleanStringForXpath** from  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13483496/3939061) to sanitize the text passed to xpath query`'//*[normalize-space(text())=normalize-space('+cleanStringForXpath(corpus[k])+')]'` ,but can't get it working.Tried adding it to `execute_script` by simple concatenation  `"""..."""+"""..."""` in python, tried passing the function as argument to execute_script and then calling `Function` constructor , tried using `%s` modifier in python but none of these yielded any results.What could possibly be the issue here ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method

```
s = (
                                """
                                (function() {
                                    var banner = document.evaluate("%s", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
                                    banner.click()
                                    var bannerr = document.evaluate("%s", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
                                    bannerr.click()
                                    var banner = document.evaluate("%s", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
                                    banner.click()
                                    var bannerr = document.evaluate("%s", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
                                    bannerr.click()
                                    var banner = document.evaluate("%s", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
                                    banner.click()
                                    var bannerr = document.evaluate("%s", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
                                    bannerr.click()
                                    var banner = document.evaluate("%s", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
                                    banner.click()
                                    var bannerr = document.evaluate("%s", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
                                    bannerr.click()
                                    var banner = document.evaluate("%s", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
                                    banner.click()
                                    var bannerr = document.evaluate("%s", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
                                    bannerr.click()
                                    var banner = document.evaluate("%s", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
                                    banner.click()
                                    var bannerr = document.evaluate("%s", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
                                    bannerr.click()
                                    var banner = document.evaluate("%s", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
                                    banner.click()
                                    var bannerr = document.evaluate("%s", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
                                    bannerr.click()
                                    var banner = document.evaluate("%s", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
                                    banner.click()


                                })()"""
                                % (js_ile_gonderme[0], js_ile_gonderme[1], js_ile_gonderme[2], js_ile_gonderme[3], js_ile_gonderme[4], js_ile_gonderme[5], js_ile_gonderme[6], js_ile_gonderme[7], js_ile_gonderme[8], js_ile_gonderme[9], js_ile_gonderme[10], js_ile_gonderme[11], js_ile_gonderme[12], js_ile_gonderme[13], js_ile_gonderme[14]))
                                try:

                                    driver.execute_script(s)
                                except:
                                    pass
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).