# How to write xpath in selenium for a text that contains Apostrophe (')

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have the following  text and i need to write x path

**Please upload this owner's ID:**

Here when i write x path with text or contains text it doesn't return the matches.

```
//*[@text()='Please upload this owner's ID:']
```

I doubt that there is an ' symbol in the word owner's and hence its not giving proper result.

Hope i can find a solution here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use apostrophe (') in xpath while finding element using webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542773/how-to-use-apostrophe-in-xpath-while-finding-element-using-webdriver)

Comment: @Andersson, I tried that but that logic didn't worked for me

Comment: Can you elaborate a little about *"...didn't worked for me"*?

Comment: try `//*[text()="Please upload this owner's ID:"]`

Comment: You'll need to clarify whether you mean `@text` the attribute, or the `text()` value . You can't have `@text()`

Comment: Post the relevant HTML or a link to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the escape sequence for a single quote (') in Xml is [`&apos;`](https://www.w3.org/standards/xml/core), there's [a limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482352/xquery-looking-for-text-with-single-quote) in `XPath 1.0` preventing `'` from being used directly in a path.

Also, as it stands, your question asks for any element with a `text` attribute containing the search string, e.g.

```
 <node text="Please upload this owner's ID:" />
```

Assuming there are no other `text` attributes with strings containing those two phases, a hacky approximation to the search would be:

```
//*[contains(@text, 'Please upload this owner') and contains(@text, 's ID:')]
```

If however you meant that the element's `text()` content needed to match (i.e. not a `text` attribute):

```
 <node>Please upload this owner's ID</node>
```

Then the same hack would be:

```
//*[contains(text(), 'Please upload this owner') and contains(text(), 's ID:')]
```

Comment: I think you might have stumbled [upon this limitation in XPath 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13482352/314291)

Comment: thank you stuart it worked. your 3rd condition worked.

Comment: Just one doubt . In general can we not use @text? in some cases when i give @text()='ABC' it gives results.'

Comment: `@xxx` means find the [value of attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/103417/314291) `xxx`, whereas `text()` means get the text value(s) under the current node. Have a look at my xml / html sample data (`<node>`) to see the difference. `@text()` shouldn't be valid IMO.

Answer (score 2):

try with double quotes.

```
 //*[@text()="Please upload this owner's ID:"]
```

or with escape

```
 //*[@text()='Please upload this owner\'s ID:']
```